# C# LINQ - Select statement that compares all properties of a class with a different instance of the same class?

Tags: c#, linq, reflection

I have the following:

```
IEnumerable<Foo<T, TOther>> Items { get; set; }

public class Foo<T, TOther>
{
    public TOther Bar { get; }

    //Somewhere in the class Bar is generated/populated
}


public void DoSomething(TOther bar)
{
    var foo = Items.Single(item => //Where all properties of item.Bar match bar);
}
```

So, is there a nice LINQ way of dynamically comparing all the properties of item.Bar with the properties of bar? Or am I gonna get stuck using reflection?

Comment: If you do not implement your own `IComparer`, you WILL have to use reflection

Comment: to be crystal clear you want to compare types of and names of properties?

Answer (score 2):

You can either implement `IComparable` (as Oskar suggested) or you need to use reflection.

If you're using reflection and you need to speed-up your code then you can emit dynamic IL ([System.Reflection.Emit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.aspx)) at run-time. See [Dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) source for an example of dynamic IL generation.

Comment: While IL emit is flexible, I'd be quite tempted to go the Expression route here (says the idiot who wrote the IL code for "dapper")

Answer (score 1):

If this is for LINQ-to-SQL etc, maybe something like:

```
static Expression<Func<T,bool>> GetComparer<T>(T obj)
{
    var c = Expression.Constant(obj, typeof(T));
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
    var members = (
        from member in typeof(T).GetMembers(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
        where member.MemberType == MemberTypes.Field || member.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property
        select Expression.Equal(Expression.MakeMemberAccess(c, member),
            Expression.MakeMemberAccess(param, member))).ToList();
    Expression body;
    if(members.Count == 0) body = Expression.Constant(true, typeof(bool));
    else body = members.Aggregate((x,y) => Expression.AndAlso(x,y));
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T,bool>>(body, param);
}
```

You can use that with LINQ-to-Objects too if you use `.AsQueryable()` first.

For example,

```
class Test
{
    public int Foo { get; set; }
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
static void Main()
{
    var data = new[] {
        new Test { Foo = 1, Bar = "a"}, new Test { Foo = 1, Bar = "b"},
        new Test { Foo = 2, Bar = "a"}, new Test { Foo = 2, Bar = "b"},
        new Test { Foo = 1, Bar = "a"}, new Test { Foo = 1, Bar = "b"},
        new Test { Foo = 2, Bar = "a"}, new Test { Foo = 2, Bar = "b"},
    };
    var findMe = new Test { Foo = 1, Bar = "b" };
    var found = data.AsQueryable().Where(GetComparer(findMe)).ToList();
    // finds 2 items, as expected
}
```

or alternatively, via `.Compile()`:

```
    var found = data.Where(GetComparer(findMe).Compile()).ToList();
    // finds 2 items, as expected
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the Reflection route (using LINQ to Objects):

```
static readonly IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> otherProps = typeof (TOther).GetProperties();

public void DoSomething (TOther thatBar)
{
    var foo = Items
        .Select (item => item.Bar)
        .Single (thisBar =>
            otherProps.All (prop =>
                prop.GetValue (thisBar, null).Equals (
                   prop.GetValue (thatBar, null)
                )
            )
        );

}
```

And be sure to watch for corner cases (e.g. indexer properties, properties you don't want to match, set-only properties, properties that can throw exceptions).

I didn't check if it compiles though so you might want to tweak the method so it does the right thing.

**However**, you should **not** do that if:

- you need this in more than one place;
- `Items` is not an in-memory list or array but a query result, as in LINQ to SQL;
- you need to do it considerably fast.

After all, according to [Information Expert](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRASP_%28object-oriented_design%29#Information_Expert) principle, since concrete `Bar` types **“know” themselves better than any other classes**, they should be given the responsibility to provide a comparison implementation.